# Select all lines in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a bunch of PowerPoint slides I need to reformat, and I'd like to figure out a way to select all lines on the page - including those with arrowheads.

I found [this post](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54473-Selecting-all-lines-connectors-on-slide) that included some VBA for selecting all lines on a slide, but it doesn't capture lines with arrowheads.  How could I update this code to grab all lines, including those with arrowheads?

```
Sub getLines()

Dim oshp As Shape
Dim osld As Slide
On Error Resume Next
Set osld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
If Not osld Is Nothing Then
For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
If oshp.Type = msoLine Then oshp.Select Replace:=msoFalse
Next oshp
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the selection to include `msAutoShape` as well as `msoLine` as follows:

```
Sub getLines()

Dim oshp As Shape
Dim osld As Slide
On Error Resume Next
Set osld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
If Not osld Is Nothing Then
For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
If (oshp.Type = msoLine Or oshp.Type = msoAutoShape) Then oshp.Select Replace:=msoFalse
Next oshp
End If

End Sub
```

I was able to figure out the VBA shape type using [this macro here](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00007_Show_me_the_-Type_of_each_object_on_a_slide.htm) which steps through every shape on a slide, and displays the object type in a window.  Super helpful!